# What is the correct way to use concat along with pipe in Rxjs 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I have a server call which may return `HTTP 202`. Influenced by [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979131/rxjs-retry-with-delay-function) thread, I have the following:

```
this.http.get(url)
  .pipe(
    map(response => {
      if (response.status === 202) {
        throw response;
      }
      return response;
    }),
    retryWhen(errors => {
      return errors.pipe(
        delay(1000),
        take(3),
        concat(response => Observable.throw('Retries exceeded'))
      );
    }),
    catchError(handleError)
  );
```

Getting a `deprecated` warning on the use of `concat`. I understand the new `concat` is in `rxjs` and not `rxjs/operator`.

But, what is the right way to use the new `static concat` operator here?

Found the following [from this site](https://auth0.com/blog/whats-new-in-rxjs-6/)

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs/operators';
a$.pipe(concat(b$, c$));

// becomes

import { concat } from 'rxjs';
concat(a$, b$, c$);
```

I'm not able to wrap my head around which `Observable`s are being concatenated in my example code?

**UPDATE 1**

Changed the code to:

```
return concat(this.http.get(url)
  .pipe(
    map(response => {
      if (response.status === 202) {
        throw response;
      }
      return response;
    }),
    retryWhen(errors => {
      return errors.pipe(
        delay(1000),
        take(3)
      );
    }),
    catchError(handleError)
  ), response => Observable.throw('Retries exceeded'));
```

But this results in:

```
core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'function (response) { return rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["Observable"].throw('Retries exceeded'); }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:6)
at
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pipeable operators are just functions that take an observable  and return an observable. So you can use the `concat` factory function like this:

```
retryWhen(errors => {
  return errors.pipe(
    delay(1000),
    take(3),
    o => concat(o, throwError('Retries exceeded'))
  );
})
```

Also, the `concat` operator is going to be replaced with/renamed to `concatWith`. See [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3927).

Comment: Changed throw to throwError for v6.x