# Correct way to use FlatMap in Rx?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

Is it correct way to use `flatMap`?

```
const observer = Observable
    .interval(3000)
    .takeUntil(Observable.timer(10000))
    .flatMap(this.askToReadyRecordVideo);

private askToReadyRecordVideo(): Observable<any> {
    return this.requestMethods.askToReadyRecordVideo({});
}
```

In this line I tied to send request to server each 3 seconds until 10 seconds then call method `this.askToReadyRecordVideo()` that returns data from server.

I finish this when I get successfull response. Is it true?

Comment: This should do what you are set up to do. except it does not stop after the get successful response. 
It will only stop on the 10th second.

Comment: How to use this right for request?

Comment: I need to stop process when I get succesfull result from server

Comment: So, it's like 10 secs or success? 10 secs has been done. IMHO, stop process on success should be the job of the subscriber. 
`observer.takeUntil(res=>!res.success)..subscribe()`

Comment: More like you would need `retry` or `retryWhen` if dealing with errors/successful calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly, but your code does the following:
The method `askToReadyRecordVideo` will get called every 3 seconds until 10 seconds are over (there will be three calls, at 3s, 6s and 9s).
Your observable `observer` will emit the results of those server calls.

If you want to cancel the process after your first successful response add the following:

```
.filter(resp => /* return true when resp indicates success */)
.take(1)
```

If every answer is a success (i.e. errors are indicated by an error event pushed through the observable), then just omit the `filter` line.

By the way: Be careful when passing callbacks to avoid surprises about what `this` means in `askToReadyRecordVideos`. You may use `flatMap(() => this.askToReadyRecordVideo())` or `flatMap(this.askToReadyRecordVideo.bind(this))` instead of `flatMap(this.askToReadyRecordVideo)`.

Comment: Can I use `filter` with condition inside to check response? And how to wait response from prev request and only then call next?

Comment: Yes, the commented block is exactly the condition to check the response's success. Maybe retry (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retry.html) or retryWhen (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html) are more appropriate in your situation. Also have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979131/rxjs-retry-with-delay-function

Comment: You know problem is that it will call next request not awaiting result from prev(fail or success)

Comment: Thank you how to start countdown from 0 not from 3 second?

Comment: Regarding the initial delay you want to avoid: have a look at this answer I found by googling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612945/how-to-get-an-observable-to-return-data-immediately-and-every-5-seconds-thereaft