# Angular Timeout in for Loop

Tags: angular, rest

At the moment I try to build a data import in Angular. All works fine, but my Backend only allows arround 70 requests. So it runs into an error. My thinking is to put a timeout in angular for Loop with post request. Is this right way to handle this problem? And if yes, how to do this? Can`t find any solution.
This is my request at the moment:

```
for( let x of this.data ){
    this.http.post(url,x,{ headers: (reqHeader)}).toPromise().then((data: any) => { console.warn(this.data) })
}
```

Comment: You basically need to retryWhen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44979389/2490286

Comment: Do you mean a total of 70 requests or 70 parallel requests at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly mean by *Backend only allows arround 70 requests*. But if you wish to control the number of parallel requests at a time, you could use RxJS `from`, `bufferCount` and `forkJoin` functions with `concatMap` operator.

1. Try to avoid `toPromise()`. It is an easier way to switch back to a familiar Promise paradigm, but it's being [deprecated](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/) in RxJS 7 and will be gone in RxJS 8. Instead try to subscribe to the observables.
2. For controlled parallel requests, try the following

```js
const reqs = this.data.map(item => this.http.post(url, item, { headers: (reqHeader) }))

from(reqs).pipe(
  bufferCount(6),      // <-- adjust number of parallel requests here
  concatMap(buffer => forkJoin(buffer))
).subscribe(
  res => console.warn(res),
  err => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('complete')
);
```

#### Update: delay each request

You could forgo the `bufferCount` and instead switch to each request individually and use an explicit delay. Try the following

```js
from(this.data).pipe(
  concatMap(item => this.http.post(url, item, { headers: (reqHeader) }).pipe(
    delay(3000)     // <-- wait 3 seconds b/n each request
  ))
).subscribe(
  res => { },
  err => { }
);
```

#### Update: count the emissions

You could introduce a variable (eg. `count`) and use the `map` operator to return both the count and the response.

Try the following

```js
someFunc() {
  let count = 0;

  from(this.data).pipe(
    concatMap(item => this.http.post(url, item, { headers: (reqHeader) }).pipe(
      map(res => {
        count++;
        return {
          count: count,
          response: res
        }
      }),
      delay(3000)     // <-- wait 3 seconds b/n each request
    ))
  ).subscribe(
    res => {
      console.log(res.count);        // <-- the count of the emission
      console.log(res.response);     // <-- the response from `this.http.post()`
    },
    err => { }
  );
}
```

Comment: I turned bufferCount(1) seams to run nice, but after arround 60 requests:   headers: {…}, status: 429, statusText: "Too Many Requests"

Comment: Does your response have a `Retry-After` header? How long is the wait time?

Comment: The wait time is about some seconds. Is there no way to put a delay inside ?

Comment: @SaschaK: I've updated the answer to have an explicit wait time b/n each request using the `delay` operator. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: < You are the hero. Thank you so much. With from code looks really nice and runs perfect. And not to forget I learned something more in Angular.

Comment: One more thing. How can I count items?

Comment: @SaschaK: Could you please elaborate? Do you wish to have the index of the item that is being emitted?

Comment: Would be great, if I could count requests in a way. And get data from res. I tried like this, but only get output as json       .subscribe(res =>{ this.myvar = res; }

Comment: @SaschaK: I've updated the answer. Please check if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you again! I didn`t knew that is so easy just to put count++ inside. Will use this code in many other projects for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [rate limiting](https://riptutorial.com/rxjs/example/30310/rate-limiting) is what you are looking for?

> ... Then we'll chain it with bufferTime and concatMap. The concatMap
> operator is where we force the 1000ms delay:

```
const startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

const source = Observable.range(1, 25)
  .concatMap(val => Observable.of(val).delay(75));

source.bufferTime(1000, null, 5)
  .concatMap(buffer => Observable.of(buffer).delay(1000))
  .timestamp()
  .map(obj => {
    obj.timestamp = obj.timestamp - startTime;
    return obj;
  })
  .subscribe(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems it`s what I need, but can`t figure out how to use with my code. Have to put it into for loop? How to import Observable.range? Shows me not exists. Thanks a lot.